# Displaying bitmaps after sometime

Tags: java, image

I have a large number of bitmap files in a directory and I want to display them using the java code (something like a slideshow) I was able to display them using a Jpanel.

But the problem is when the next image gets displayed the jframe blinks.I want the next image to appear without blinking. What should I do??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading and showing the new image (can you show your code)? Don't forget that this takes time and this may be what is causing your blinking or flicker.

Standard practice is to load the image and only change it when it has been prepared and buffered.

Comment: Actually I was creating the instance of jpanel again n again to show the images.. which was making it blink when every new instance was created. But now I am doing it on the same panel by calling graphics.drawimage method again n again .. Anyways thanks again